# FTP/FXP server-to-server transfer via SSL/TLS

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I want to build a connection between two (FXPable) FTP-Servers and transfer a folder with subfolders and files in it.

As an an example I want to copy (FXP - site-to-site) the whole `/www/xy.com` from server 1 to `/www/xy.com` on server 2 but I have no idea how to do that.

I found an interesting module on PyPI called "ftpext", but I do not understand it correctly. This module includes FXP and PRET support. Also what I want to use. So maybe someone could help me. I don't need that module if you can do it differently.

Here is the link:

- [FTPEXT](https://pypi.org/project/ftpext/)
- [HOW TO FXP](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/FXP.html)

My script should be able to do:

```
usage: %s SERVER1 PORT1 USER1 PASS1 PATH_TO_FOLDER1 SERVER2 PORT2 USER2 PASS2 PATH_TO_DESTINATION_FOLDER
```

This is an output of my current script:

```
CONNECTiON ESTABLiSHED OVER SSL/TLS TO SERVER 1: *.*.*.*

switched to secure data connection

Changed directory on Server1 successfully to: www

CONNECTiON ESTABLiSHED OVER SSL/TLS TO SERVER 2: *.*.*.*

switched to secure data connection

Changed directory on Server2 successfully to: www
```

And here is my script (It is really quick and dirty without error handling):

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import sys

# SECURE CONNECT TO FTP1 OVER TLS/SSL

ftps1 = FTP_TLS
ftps1 = FTP_TLS.port = sys.argv[2]
ftps1 = FTP_TLS('%s' % sys.argv[1])
ftps1.login(sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
print("CONNECTiON ESTABLiSHED OVER SSL/TLS TO SERVER 1: %s" % sys.argv[1])
print()
ftps1.prot_p()
print("switched to secure data connection")
print()
ftps1.cwd(sys.argv[5])
print("Changed directory on Server1 successfully to: %s" % sys.argv[5])
print()

# SECURE CONNECT TO FTP2 OVER TLS/SSL

ftps2 = FTP_TLS
ftps2 = FTP_TLS.port = sys.argv[7]
ftps2 = FTP_TLS('%s' % sys.argv[6])
ftps2.login(sys.argv[8], sys.argv[9])
print("CONNECTiON ESTABLiSHED OVER SSL/TLS TO SERVER 2: %s" % sys.argv[6])
print()
ftps2.prot_p()
print("switched to secure data connection")
print()
ftps2.cwd(sys.argv[10])
print("Changed directory on Server2 successfully to: %s" % sys.argv[10])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for `FTPExt.fxp_to` or `FTPExt.secure_fxp_to` methods:

```
ftp1 = FTPExt(host1, port1, user1, password1, True)
ftp2 = FTPExt(host2, port2, user2, password2, True)

ftp1.fxp_to(path1, ftp2, path2)
```

Comment: Thank you :). I got a SyntaxError: invalid syntax with the solution above so I tried to do with "" because of python3 and got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is you get "syntax error"? Where do you get "type error" now?

Comment: My mistake: from ftpext.ftpext import FTPExt. But now I got TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'port', 'user', and 'password'

Comment: I only used import ftpext before. I used also FTPExt(host, port, user, pass, True, False, 0) Still the same error with missing required positional arguments...

Comment: Whoops. Sorry. the connecting part --> ftp1 = FTPExt(host1, port1, user1, password1, True)

Comment: I do not see how you can get that error, if you clearly pass 5 parameters. I do not get any error. Post a complete error message with all details.

Comment: FTPExt('**.**.**:**, 7777, test, test123, True')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'port', 'user', and 'password'

Comment: That's not my code! You are passing only single string parameter. Use `FTPExt('*.*.*.*', 7777, 'test', 'test123', True)`.

Comment: Oh my g0d. I'm so stupid :-\. embarrassing... Connection to both servers now working :) Thanks! Did you test fxp transfer by accident? I got "ftplib.error_perm: 553 Error:" (no upload rights in this dir - but that's wrong) I think maybe the wrong destination path was chosed or something else. I'm no python expert so please be lenient :) I tested with ftp1.secure_fxp_to('/www/source/test.rar', ftp2, '/www/target/') and with ftp1.secure_fxp_to('/www/source/', ftp2, '/www/target/'). I got the same error with bot sources.

Comment: Both path arguments to `(secure_)fxp_to` are paths to **files**, not directories. So `ftp1.secure_fxp_to('/www/source/test.rar', ftp2, '/www/target/test.rar')`